# create an UML class diagram for puppet modules

Tags: uml, puppet, class-diagram

I have developed a puppet script for automating openstack configurations.
Now i have to make an UML diagram to model my puppet script. I need to make a class diagram. But i didn't figure how.

So my questions are :

what is the suitable way to modeling puppet script?

If we can use An UML class diagram,  how is that possible and is there an example?

Thanks.

Comment: if your're going to make UML diagrams use http://creately.com/Draw-UML-and-Class-Diagrams-Online or Gliffy http://www.gliffy.com/

Comment: @RachelGallen i don't need an Uml editor but an overview for puppet class diagram

Comment: UML can document what is going on in the system when your puppet script is applied. As @Felix-frank points it may not be best tool do document how the scripts look like. For how to use UML for modeling behavior and examples take a look at http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index-examples.html and http://agilemodeling.com/style/activityDiagram.htm (and their neighborhoods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UML is of very limited use for modeling Puppet manifest code, seeing as UML diagrams depict

- structure
- behavior
- interaction

Behavior and interaction do not apply to Puppet, because its language is not imperative - it's declarative.

You could try and represent your [defined types](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/definedtypes.html) in [structure diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language#Structure_diagrams), but it is an ill fit because defined type instances are not actual rvalues.

Behavior diagrams might be feasible to depict the behavior of the agent on a system given a piece of code, but those would be trivial and very repetitive, seeing as you'd basically need to maintain a simple diagram for each and every property of each resource in your manifest.

I don't recommend the UML direction at all. Please note that Puppet is **not a scripting engine**, and a Puppet manifest is not a script! It's a collection of resources for a Puppet agent to manage.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So if it is not appropriate to use uml diagrams to represent the design of puppet code, then how would i design my code? do i have just to use the dependency graph? and thanks

Comment: My personal take is that the Puppet DSL serves as a modeling language in and of itself. If you want a graphical representation, you could likely transform your manifest by picking three node types (class, define, resource) and two edge types (include and declare). For the higher level concepts such as virtual resources, you may still need to vary the nodes and edges, but it might indeed work.

Comment: Oh cool, you did that already. I will elaborate in answer to that.